# Teamcity upgrade fails when unpacking plugins

Tags: windows-10, teamcity

Well, I've seen there are lots of people who have issues with TeamCity's agent upgrading. But I haven't seen anyone who has the same problem as I do.

I currently run the JetBrains toolsuite for evaluation on my Windows 10 machine (which I assume should do fine). But ever since I installed TeamCity, the default agent is stuck in the upgrade process.

Here see the [teamcity-agent.log](https://pastebin.com/23d7e3Gr) and the [upgrade.log](https://pastebin.com/PUgn1g9Q). It's just that one plugin "java-dowser.zip" which cannot be extracted. I tried shutting it down and manually unpacking it - but it just deletes all unpacked folders and tries again failing all over.

I really don't get why and moreover can't find anyone having the same issue... I installed the service using the "SYSTEM" user and gave ownership to the whole folder including full access permissions.

What is causing this? Also tried disabling Bitdefender. Did not work either.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a single plugin (dotnet.cli) but the error was `Failed to unpack plugin: "Failed to parse teamcity-plugin.xml from plugin: ***\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnet.cli.zip. Failed to parse plugin descriptor. Error on line 3: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'teamcity-plugin'.`   I ended up having to stop the TeamCity server and delete the ".unpacked" directory.

Answer (score 1):

The actual troublemaker was (like I had expected it) Bitdefender. The problem was that Bitdefender never showed an issue when scanning the plugin files of the TC agent. Once I uninstalled the default one and installed a new one manually into another directory it actually showed a message that it was disinfecting "java-dowser.zip".

The JetBrains support told me that this is currently a false-positive for many AV solutions. Whitelisting solved the problem. Weirdly it did not work when I whitelisted the default installation folder...

No point for Bitdefender here.